# New subsubsection without any space after the title

Tags: sectioning

This is part of my code:

```
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \setcounter{subsubsection}{411}
    \subsubsection{Root calculation.}
    The easiest way to..
```

It has to look the same as :

```
\textbf{412. Root calculation.} The easiest way..
```

I can't use \textbf, I have to use sth like subsection command, but this sign before 412 can't be there and text "The easiest way.." has to start in the same line. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{411}
% we don't want reset subsubsection numbers
\counterwithout{subsubsection}{subsection}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\bfseries\normalsize}{\thesubsubsection.}{0.333em}{}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{411}

\subsubsection{Root calculation.}
The easiest way to …

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added this package, but don't know where I should put the other line? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You can put it anywhere in your preamble. The simplest seems to be just after titlesec loading.

Comment: I'm getting: 'Paragraph ended before \ttl@format@i was complete.' when pasting it in my preamble.

Comment: Sorry, I had lost a closing brace. Please see the updated code

Comment: \usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsubsection[runin]}{\bfseries\normalsize}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{}                                                              Tried this one but still I'm getting some errors like :Missing \endcsname inserted. ...ies\normalsize}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{} or Undefined control sequence. ...ies\normalsize}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{}

Comment: @Thomas: You forgot the closing brace after `subsubsection`. Please take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without any package specialized in section title formatting, with some acrobatics:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

% we don't want reset subsubsection numbers
\counterwithout{subsubsection}{subsection}

\makeatletter
% a negative value in the 5th argument to \@startsection means "run in"
\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {-\fontdimen2\font \@plus -\fontdimen3\font \@minus -\fontdimen4\font}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

% we don't want a quad of space between number and title in subsubsections
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  % the number
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \ifcsname #1spacing\endcsname
    % something else for chosen levels
    \csname#1spacing\endcsname
  \else
    % quad for the others
    \quad
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\subsubsectionspacing}{. }% period space

\begin{document}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{411}

\section{Whatever}

\subsection{Again}

\subsubsection{Root calculation.}
The easiest way to

\end{document}
```

[image]